# Jenkins Role Based Authorization Strategy Plugin Inconsistent behavior for different users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**Current State**: I have implemented project based roles strategy (also called the item roles) and have the appropriate project folder level regex etc set up. And I have verified the regexes and other permissions work fine for most logged in users, except the below scenarios I am running into.

- Plugin Version: 3.2
- Jenkins Version: 2.263.4
- Jenkins Authentication Provider: LDAP Connecting to Active Directory
- Example regex(es): for project role dev = `^ABC\-DEF\/DEV\/.*`

**Issue**: Certain users are only having issues while going through the project role based authorization plugin where they are not able to see the option to run builds or job configurations. While the same configurations work for a couple of other user who have the same permissions.

*Example*:
Users - `adm-XXXX` and `adm-YYYY` and a few more all starting with the prefix of `adm`- are not able to get the roles for the configure and run builds on the jobs based on the above regex.

While Users - `adm-zzzz` and others are able to get the same roles using the same permission matrix.

The issue is very inconsistent as some days it would work, and even the same configurations when I tested in another Jenkins instance it worked for the user - `adm-XXXX` so I am at a loss on how to debug why it does not work for a few users consistently. I can understand if it is a configuration issue it should not work for all users having the same role.

Are there any tips on enabling some extra debug to troubleshoot this since there are literally a couple of loggers in the code of the plugin.

Appreciate the help here from any one knowledegable.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, where associating an LDAP/AD user to a local global role or item/project role with build and configure permissions enabled does not enable this permission in the project itself. The option to build and configure is not available.

The only way I got around this was to add the users into AD groups and associating the AD Group to a role with required permissions.

Enabling the exact same permissions on the AD group role that I had on the local role, enabled the build and configure option in the projects.

I am not sure if this is a bug, an AD integration issue that you cannot mix/match local and AD roles or I am missing some option or if anyone has managed to get around this anomoly - but this workaournd seems to overcome this.